# group by average no of hours

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

i have data
df:

```
month   name    duration
5       abc     09:03:00
5       abc     09:09:00
5       eef     10:03:00
5       eef     09:03:00
5       eef     09:03:00
5       ttk     10:03:00
5       abc     09:03:00
5       ttk     09:23:00
6       ttk     09:03:00
6       abc     11:03:00
```

I need to groupby this to get results like this:

```
month   name    name_size   name_nuique duration_mean
5       abc     3           1           09:05:00
        eef     3           1           09:23:00
        ttk     2           1           09:43:00
6       abc     1           1           09:03:00
        ttx     1           1           11:03:00
```

Please let me know how to do this.
I tried doing

```
df.groupby(['month','name'], sort=False).agg({'name':['size','nunique'],
          'duration':['mean']})
```

But i get error saying:

> No numeric types to aggregate

Comment: `duration` is a string. You cannot apply `mean` to a column of strings.

Comment: i tried converting this string into timedelta jj['duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(jj['duration']) now its dtype: timedelta64[ns] but still i get the same error while applying mean. please let me know what should i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard pandas `mean()` cannot handle timedeltas. After converting the column to timedeltas, apply a custom lambda function to it:

```
df["duration"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["duration"])
df.groupby(["month", "name"], sort=False).agg({
                               "name": ["size", "nunique"],
                               "duration": [lambda x: x.mean()]})
```

Comment: thanks a lot. also df["duration"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["duration"]) didnt worked for me. i had to use df["duration"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["duration"].astype(str))